# Classificar em ordem decrescente um .txt que contém um registro com nome e número

Tags: java, classificação

Criei um quiz com 10 perguntas que solicita o nome do usuário no começo da aplicaçao e ao fim da execução das perguntas, registra em um .txt o nome e a quantidade de acertos, exemplo:

> ```
> 3  - Edu
> 5  - Bob
> 10 - Eloa
> 9  - Max
> ```

Meu objetivo com esse .txt seria criar como se fosse um placar de lideres, porém não consegui nenhuma solução de ordenar os dados do arquivo de forma decrescente, a fim da pessoa que acertou mais questões do quiz fique em primeiro.
exemplo:

> ```
> 10 - Eloa
> 9  - Max
> 5  - Bob
> 3  - Edu
> ```

```
Functions.digita("\nPONTOS: " + contPontos + "\nParabéns " + Main.nomeJogador
            + ", sua pontuação foi registrada no placar de líderes!!!", milisPorChar);
    String registroPlacar = contPontos+"  - " + Main.nomeJogador+"\r\n";
    Functions.atualizarPlacar(registroPlacar);

public static void atualizarPlacar(String l) {
    try {
        String line = l;
        File file = new File("./PlacarLideres.txt");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getPath(), true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(line);
        bufferWritter.flush();
        bufferWritter.close();
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Acredito que o jeito mais simples seria seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Ler todas as linhas do arquivo e guardar numa lista
2. Adicionar a nova pontuação
3. Ordenar a lista com base nos pontos
4. Reescrever a lista atualizada no arquivo

Para ler o arquivo já como uma lista, vc faz assim:

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
/* ... */
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of("PlacarLideres.txt"));
```

Para ordenar a lista de acordo com os pontos, vc faria algo assim:

```java
Collections.sort(lines, (String a, String b) -> {
  int pointsA = Integer.parseInt(a.split("-")[0].trim());
  int pointsB = Integer.parseInt(b.split("-")[0].trim());

  return Integer.compare(pointsB, pointsA);
});
```

Veja que como eu já sei o hífen é usado para separar os pontos dos nomes, basta eu fazer um `split` nele e, em seguida, converter para um `int`.

Por último, basta escrever a lista no arquivo. Assim:

```java
Files.write(Path.of("PlacarLideres.txt"), lines);
```

Aqui está um exemplo completo:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Game {
  private static final Path path = Path.of("PlacarLideres.txt");

  private static void update(String line) {
    try {
      if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        Files.createFile(path);
      }

      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

      lines.add(line);

      Collections.sort(lines, (String a, String b) -> {
        int pointsA = Integer.parseInt(a.split("-")[0].trim());
        int pointsB = Integer.parseInt(b.split("-")[0].trim());

        return Integer.compare(pointsB, pointsA);
      });

      Files.write(path, lines);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    update("6 - João");
  }
}
```

Comment: ficou otimo,e mais importante me ajudou bastante a compreender a sua logica, eternamente grato.